# How to support CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS for oracle database for jdbi?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbi

We have a framework where we need to create a table if it doesn't exist. TABLE IF NOT EXISTS is not supported for Oracle. Any suggestion on how to implement it for Oracle database using jdbi?

Comment: Why not a stupid approach? Select from the table, if it doesn't exists (exception / error), create it?

Comment: Or, even *more stupid* - just issue CREATE TABLE statement. If it exists, it won't be created. Ignore the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach for you.

Create function that returns TRUE is the table exists, FALSE if it doesn't:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_exists ( p_table IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
      l_dummy NUMBER;
      l_found BOOLEAN := FALSE:
   BEGIN
      SELECT 1 INTO l_dummy
      FROM   user_tables
      WHERE table_name = p_table;
      l_found := SQL%FOUND;
      RETURN ( l_found );
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
         RETURN ( FALSE );
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE:
   END fn_exists;
```

Then, use it like this:

```
   BEGIN
      IF NOT fn_exists ( 'THE_TABLE' ) THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE TABLE THE_TABLE ....';
      END IF;
   END;
```

Or a procedure to wrap this:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_crt_if_not_exists 
   (
      p_table   IN VARCHAR2, 
      p_crt_sql IN VARCHAR2
   ) IS
   BEGIN
       IF NOT fn_exists ( p_table ) THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_crt_sql;
       END IF;
   END pr_crt_if_not_exists;
```

Then use:

```
   BEGIN
      pr_crt_if_not_exists ( 'THE_TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE THE_TABLE ...' );
      pr_crt_if_not_exists ( 'THE_TABLE2', 'CREATE TABLE THE_TABLE2 ...' );
      .
      .
   END;
```